# Error deleting files

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems

Something went very badly wrong when copying and pasting some files (not quite sure what!).
I now have sevral files within a tree of directories. ie 
(C:\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender\BtSender)

When trying to delete them I get the below error;

"The source filename(s) are larger than is supported by the filesystem. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name or try renaming to shorter names(s_ before attempting this opperation"

I need to delete them as the folder is taking up several gigs.

The only way I have found of deleting them is moving a folder to the C drive and deleting it from there. There are several folders with each folder so doing this for each one would take forever.

Im using server 2008

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from the parent folder (the first BTSender folder) and rename it to 1 and try to delete it. If you get the same message then rename the first child level folder to 1 and try again. Keep doing this until you're able to delete the entire set of folders. I've used this method many times to shorten a path in order to delete a set of folders and it's rarely taken renaming more than a handful of folders to get to the point where the path was shorten enough to delete the entire set of folders.